# Facebook login APP for any domain

Tags: facebook, symfony, dns, facebook-oauth, fosfacebookbundle

I have an app on Facebook to login. I want to use in multiple domains without having to add in the configuration panel.

In the *APP -> Settings -> Advanced*, in the field `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` I see that you can add more domains but I don't want add all domains that are require.

I like to work with the other domains?

I'm using `Symfony 2` with `FosFacebookBundle`.

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible. You have to use login on only one top domain

Comment: and by modifying the dialog javascript?

Comment: It is not possible because of the server. So you can modify the javascript as much as you want and still not be able to do it